# Divide Matrix for an input pair

Tags: r, matrix

```
 n=c(0,200,500)
 m=as.matrix(expand.grid( n,n)) 
 m #possible combin.
```

I want to get all possible pairs (a < b) to run them later in a function to filter a matrix.

```
#pairs should be somehow like this (a always smaller than b in each single attribute of the two attribute vector)
a=c(0,0)
b=c(200,200)
...
a=(200,0)
b=(500,200)
...
a=c(200,200)
b=c(500,500)
```

I want to get the results stored in a matrix with i.e. one row of it looking like:     c(a, b)
      c(0,200,    200,500)

On [lower.tri](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lower.tri.html) there was something written about how to divide a matrix, I tried around but without success.

For better understanding imagine each row of the possible combinations is a vector. First element of the vector is flight time in minutes. Second one is the price.
Searching for a flight with a price between $500 and $500 doesn't make too much sense. Neither does it, when the flights minimum price is 500$ and the maximum price 200$. "a" is always minimum parameter and "b" maximum parameter

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to achieve (maybe it's just me though).

Comment: @DavidArenburg I need to get out of these values the pairs where "a" is always smaller than "b". (=lower filtering frontier smaller than upper filtering frontier)

Comment: What do you mean by "pairs"? why `a` and `b` always contain two values?

Comment: @DavidArenburg because the combinations I calculated in "m" contain a vector in each row with two attributes (...(n,n)) . With pairs I mean that I need to get out of the combinationset "m" each time two rows of which one is smaller than the other (a<b). It would be best if I create a new matrix with the couples of vectors written next to each other

Comment: It would be nice to see how a complete desired output should look like (for example, the matrix you just mentioned)

Comment: "On lower.tri there was something written about how to divide a matrix". This is not very clear. Could you please try to explain your ultimate goal, both in words and with a tiny toy example.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but maybe this:

```
combn(nrow(m), 2, function(ind, mat) mat[ind, ], mat = m)
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]  200    0
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]  500    0
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    0  200
#
#...
```

**Edit:**

After your comment, maybe this:

```
m1 <- m[order(rowSums(m)),] #this is one definition of "smaller"

combs <- combn(nrow(m1), 2, function(ind, mat) mat[ind, ], mat = m1)
combs[,, apply(combs, 3, function(mat) diff(rowSums(mat)) != 0)]
```

**Edit 2:**

```
m1 <- m[order(m[,1]),]

combs <- combn(nrow(m1), 2, function(ind, mat) mat[ind, ], mat = m1)
combs[,, apply(combs, 3, function(mat) mat[2,2] > mat[1,2])]
```

If that's still not exactly what you need, you should be able to adjust it.

Comment: you calculated all possible combinations, but I need to get out of these values the pairs where "a" is always smaller than "b". (=lower filtering frontier smaller than upper filtering frontier)

Comment: You are really not expressing your goal very clearly.

Comment: thanks, almost. Now the rowsums are bigger in every second line. But each single attribute in the vector should be bigger in the second row. In addition it would be great if a<b and not a<=b. Imagine searching for a flight with a price between $500 and $500, it doesn't make too much sense. Neither does it, when the flights minimum price is 500$ and the maximum price 200$. For better understanding imagine first attribute inside a vector would be flight time in minutes and second the price

Comment: I tried again. Please take some time to understand the code and make further adjustments yourself.